# Xcode can't export with "Member" and Distribution Certificate (P12)

Tags: xcode

Before this error show up, my account is always set to "Member" and the client only sent me the *Distribution Certificate (P12)* that I install in my machine. This setup works fine without problem and we're able to release multiple versions of the app into the AppStore.

But when the certificate get expired (just this month), I ask the client to send me a new one which they did. I was able to installed the new certificate successfully (as I can see the certificate and private key in the Keychain Access app) but when I tried to export the app the Xcode show this error:

[image]

Any idea why suddenly Xcode showing this error? My guess right now is something is wrong with the new certificate the client provided, but I'll ask them to generate a new one if I'm sure this is something in their end and not in my end.

Any suggestion is very much appreciated!

TIA!

**UPDATE:**
So I tried the "Manually manage signing" and select the correct certificate and profile then I was able to export the app. So is this something wrong in xcode's "Automatically manage signing" when distributing the app?

Comment: Apple unified the app store connect and the apple developer into one permission. Please check out https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/ for the same.

Comment: @SachinVas I don't think the change would cause this error. I tried the "Manually manage signing" and I was able to sign the app without the error.

Comment: Manually managing the sign in confirms that the certificate is fine. Can you also upload the photo of your Account in the Xcode Preference?

Comment: @SachinVas, the Xcode Preference > Accounts show same number of account in the image above. The last account in the image above is the account the client invited into their Apple developer program thus it shows as "Member" the first in the account is my personal account.

Comment: From the above error, it looks like your role should be Developer to generate the signing assets. In the case of manual sign-in, you are just using the Provisioning Profiles which are created by the client.

Comment: @SachinVas I checked in https://developer.apple.com/account and the role of my account is "Developer" (displayed in Membership > Your Roles). For now, I'll probably have to change my Fastlane to use manual signing for this specific app since the "automatic" signing doesn't work. Thanks!